# DF - drop rows on combination of columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove/drop rows based on multiple conditions e.g values of two columns

[image: DF]

I want to remove the row where index is 'Karl' & age =60 / if index=='Karl' & age=60 :

I am trying to get the DF without the row where index is 'Karl' & age =60. If I can remove the row then df will be with the rows that I want, the other option would be filtering it. either way is fine as long as I can get the DF without the row/rows that meet the conditon

Comment: `out = df.query('(index != "Karl") | (age != "60")')`